# How to get the opened pty for a given background process (without login) in AIX

Tags: terminal, aix, background-process, pty

Using this answer [`https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283521/114939`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283521/114939) which allow us to find processes that keep an given pty opened without login (`who` command cannot show them), caused me to ask the inverse.

How to get the opened pty(s) for a given process in AIX systems ? (for those launched in background and not "attached" to a terminal/pty login).

Comment: Did you try `lsof` or `fuser`?

Comment: fuser in my case (AIX systems) doesn't shows files for a given process, but the inverse, processes for a given file.

Comment: Yes but we have file globbing: `fuser /dev/tty* /dev/pts/*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AIX has a `/proc` filesystem (since about 5.1?) and you can list the open file descriptors for a pid with [procfiles](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds4/procfiles.htm?lang=en):

```
$ procfiles -n 15502
15502 : /home/guest/test 
  Current rlimit: 2000 file descriptors                                 
   0: S_IFCHR mode:0622 dev:10,4  ino:2584 uid:100 gid:100 rdev:28,1
  O_RDONLY
   1: S_IFCHR mode:0622 dev:10,4  ino:2584 uid:100 gid:100 rdev:28,1
  O_RDONLY
   2: S_IFCHR mode:0622 dev:10,4  ino:2584 uid:100 gid:100 rdev:28,1
  O_RDONLY
   3: S_IFREG mode:0644 dev:10,7  ino:26 uid:100 gid:100 rdev:0,0       
  O_RDONLY size:0  name:/tmp/foo
```

For open devices like a pty only the inode and major/minor numbers are given, but you should be able to easily match these with those shown by a simple `ls -l /dev/pts/`.

You can also install the [AIX Toolbox for Linux Applications](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/index.html) and then use the `lsof` command.

Answer (score 0):

If XXX is the `pid`

`file /proc/XXX/fd/* | grep /dev/pt`

But you will  get multiple lines per pty if the process has it open for multiple roles  (like stdin stdout and stderr)

But I guess this won't help for AIX vs Linux, unless AIX has changed a lot since I last used it

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that there is an AIX system (not Linux).

Comment: yeah, I revised the answer when I saw one of your other comments, and then came back saw this one